# laravel 5.4: pessimistic locking. Avoid a row to be selected until transaction is finished

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, transactions, locking

I am storing financial transactions in a database.
For efficiency reasons in the transaction row i save the ammount and also the balance of the account.
For example:

ID | TRANSACTION_AMOUNT | ACCOUNT_BALANCE

ACCOUNT_BALANCE in a new row is calculated as the last ACCOUNT_BALANCE + the new TRANSACTION_AMOUNT.

To proceed with this operation i need to do first a SELECT and then an INSERT.
The issue is if two transactions came almost at the same time. Both of them will read the same last ACCOUNT_BALANCE and after the inserts the ACCOUNT_BALANCE with be inconsistent.

I have seen the function lockForUpdate() but im not completly sure how to use it for this case or even if apply.

Whats the best approach to solve this?

Comment: You can use laravel scheduled job to update account_balance later instead of doing both of them togther.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use Database Transactions. For instance

`BEGIN WORK;
SELECT account_balance FROM transaction;
-- up the account balance then commit
UPDATE account_balance SET account_balance = new_balance;
COMMIT;`